# Jqgrid: Resize to fit image in the grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have an image in a grid. I would like the image to resize to fit into the grid column, and to be horizontally and vertically centered. 
My jqgrid looks like:

```
name: "frontimageurl", sortable: false, width: 100, height: 50, align: "center", fixed: true,
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
return "<img src='" + cellvalue + "'>";
```

My image looks like overlapping of image.

Kindly help me to acheive this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added a class,

```
"<img src='" + cellvalue + "' class= Image>";
```

CSS:

```
 .Image
{
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

This works perfect for me.